# How can I fix Marytts MCEPMaker error on Windows 8

Tags: marytts

I have spend almost a week to figure it out the problem related to `Marrtts MCEPmaker` for `Windows`. I think `MCEPmaker` requires speech_tools and festival.

For this reason, I tried to install the packages in festival 2.1 folder in festvox website (which contains speech_tools as well). I have tried to use the steps stated in [here](http://www.eguidedog.net/doc/doc_build_win_festival.php).

I face with the following problems (when I tried to install with cygwin):

1. cd speech_tools `$ ./configure`. This step works perfectly
2. make VCMakefilees
   does not work. However, when I rename the file `C:\festival21\speech_tools\config\systems\ix86_Darwin` to `C:\festival21\speech_tools\config\systems\ix86_unknown` the command works (Is this renaming correct?)
3. `nmake /nologo /FVCMakefile` (With command prompt I tried with VS2009, VS2012 and VS2014). Not working. With the following error

   > NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\BIN\link.exe"' : return code '0x49d'
   >
   > NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\BIN\nmake.exe"' : return code '0x2'

   (Same result also observed with VS2009)

   I would appreciate to help me solve the problem with this error.
4. I try to run MCEPMaker of marytts by setting `db.estDir as C:\festival21\speech-tools\`

   I get an error stating that "C:\festival21\speech-tools\bin\ch_wave" does not exist

   Similar error to [that](http://www.dfki.de/pipermail/mary-users/2011-April/000801.html)

How can I get the folder/file ch_wave?

Answer (score 1):

You need Linux to build voices, it is hopeless to try it on Windows. Simply run Linux inside Virtualbox VM.